# What the syntax in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6

How arguments list should be read ? What the syntax in arguments list - the one like object definition but with equality signs?

```
Media.configureVideo = function (session, uploadId, caption, durationms, delay, {
  audio_muted = false,
  trim_type = 0,
  source_type = 'camera',
 // ...
} = {}) {
 // ... Body of the function
```

PS The code from this repository
https://github.com/huttarichard/instagram-private-api

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: There's a lot of syntax in those lines of code. Which bit do you not understand?

Comment: If you're asking how to declare a JavaScript object, you really need a [better reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Thats object destructuring with a default value.

Comment: @tadman theres no object created here at all ( except one does not pass a value)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: @Jonasw,  Could you give a link to understand this syntax?

Comment: @Jonasw I'm thinking that `audio_muted` and such is an attempt at passing in options that way based on the use of `,` there, but it could be a wildly misguided destructuring call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) a function argument, with default values, plus a default value for the argument as a whole, in case it is omitted entirely

Consider normal destructuring:

```
{ a, b } = objectWithProps;
```

which is equivalent to

```
a = objectWithProps.a;
b = objectWithProps.b;
```

You can also add default values:

```
{ a = 5 } = objectWithPropsMaybe;
```

which is equivalent to

```
if(objectWithPropsMaybe.a === undefined) {
    a = objectWithPropsMaybe.a;
} else {
    a = 5;
}
```

You can also use destructuring on function arguments to create local variables inside a function:

```
function foo({ a, b }) {
    return a + b;
}

foo({ a: 2, b: 3 });
```

And the destructuring can have default values:

```
function foo({ a=0, b=0 }) {
    return a + b;
}

foo({ a: 2 });
```

Finally, the destructuring can have a fallback target in case no argument is supplied at all:

```
function foo({ a=0, b=0 } = {}) {
    return a + b;
}

foo();
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it es6 syntax ?

Comment: @juriy yes.   .    .

Answer (score 1):

The code can be broken down to this snippet, which contains weird stuff only:

```
const sth = function ( { test = true } = {} ){ }
```

So thats a function expression, but it has so called *default parameters* , that means if you dont pass a value, e.g.

```
sth();
```

This special part fills in the value for you:

```
= {}
```

So if you dont pass a value it rather takes an empty object. Now it goes on with *object destructuring*, take this example:

```
 const {key} = {key:"value"};
 console.log(key) // "value"
```

So object destructuring just moves the keys as variables into the context, the upper equals:

```
const key = {key:"value"}.key;
```

So now putting it all together:

```
{    
   audio_muted = false,
   trim_type = 0,
   source_type = 'camera',
   // ...
} = {}
```

This sets the variables *audio_muted* and so on based on the keys with the same name in the passed object and if they're not passed the values are set.